# Need query to return Null fields if no associated data in joined table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to design a query in Access 2003 that returns information for a directory.  One of the values I wish to include is contained in a second table, but that table doesn't have records for all the records I want.

I want a directory line for EACH `MomID` in table `Registration,` regardless of whether that `MomID` is referenced in table `Kids`.  I can't just leave it out, because if there *are* children listed in `Kids`, that needs to be in the directory.

Currently, my query returns only those records where `MomID` is in both `Registration` and `Kids`.  I'm filtering the data so that I only get records from `Registration` with the current `YearStart` field, so I can't make it an OR statement (even if I knew how).  How do I get EVERY record in `Registration` which meets the `YearStart` criterion, and have the query return an empty field if the relevant `MomID` isn't present in `Kids`"

I *could* just go manually add `MomID` to `Kids` and leave the other fields blank, but that solution lacks elegance.  I'm also not entirely sure that would work, since I'm running the data in `Kids` through two other queries to sort and concatenate before pulling it into the directory query.  Plus, I'd like to retain the ability to include childless individuals in the directory if I ever want to expand the database to include the volunteers associated with the group.

Comment: It sounds like you need to use an LEFT JOIN to include all records from the table on the left regardless of if there is a record on the right.  If you can give us the table structure, a query, and/or explain how the tables link together, then we might be able to help you.

Answer (score 3):

What you're describing is a classic case of [LEFT JOIN](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/left-join-right-join-operations-HP001032251.aspx). This operator brings ALL records from the left part of the join even if there're no matches in the right part,

In your case it would be something like

```
SELECT * FROM Registration LEFT JOIN Kids ON Registration.MomID = Kids.MomID
WHERE Registration.YearStart = Year(Date())
```

Substitute * with only needed fields if you don't need all the fields from both tables.